# how to convert trigger 'if inserting' from oracle to mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, mariadb, sql-insert, database-trigger

I have been trying to convert trigger from oracle to MySQL/MariaDB. I'm still new in MySQL so I'm still figuring.

This is the table structure from the table that I'm doing the trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
  `attendanceid` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `studentname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `atdate` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

I've already created a sequence table for the trigger as below :

```
CREATE TABLE `att_seq` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

This is the code from oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "STUDENT"."CLASSID" 
BEFORE INSERT ON attendance
FOR EACH ROW
declare
BEGIN
 if :new.attendanceid is null then
                  select 'ATT' || attandance_seq.nextval into :new.attendanceid from dual;

    if inserting then
            if(:new.classname = '4A') then
            :new.classid := 'CLASS401';
            end if;
            if(:new.classname = '4B') then
            :new.classid := 'CLASS402';
            end if;
             if(:new.classname = '4C') then
            :new.classid := 'CLASS403';
            end if;
    end if;
  end if;
END;
/
```

and this is by far how I have converted it (p/s: the 'update class..' code is a new code that i added from the oracle one):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER att_auto_id
BEFORE INSERT ON attendance
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO att_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.attendanceid = CONCAT('ATT', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '00'));
  
  IF inserting THEN
    IF new.classname = `4A` THEN
        SET new.classid = `CLASS401`;
        UPDATE class 
        SET classid = new.classid;
    END IF;
    IF new.classname = `4B` THEN
        SET new.classid = `CLASS402`;
        UPDATE class 
        SET classid = new.classid;
    END IF;
    IF new.classname = `4C` THEN
        SET new.classid = `CLASS403`;
        UPDATE class 
        SET classid = new.classid;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END $$
```

when I run it, I get this error:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'inserting' in 'field list'

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me. Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: I'm sure you're close. Out of curiosity, does [ORACLE mode](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql_modeoracle-from-mariadb-103/). `LAST_INSERT_ID` doesn't look right, its from the previous insert. `OLD.pk IS NULL` might be the way to determine `inserting`.

Comment: mariadb-10.3 has [sequence objects](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequences/) too

Comment: Can't insert NULL on NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inserting` key word in Oracle triggers helps you to determine if the trigger was invoked by an insert operation because in Oracle you can define a trigger to be invoked by multiple events (e.g. before insert or update).

However, in mysql a trigger can only be invoked by a single event, so there is no need for this key word in mysql. Simply do not have the `if inserting then` condition in your code.

Also, formatting the sequence value in the table is wrong - either format the value when you display it in your application or use [zerofill](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) property when declaring the column. This way you can use an auto_increment column directly in the table.

The declaration of the sequence table is missing the auto_increment property. The field is also declared as `not null`, so you cannot use `null` to generate a new auto_increment value. Use either a nullable field or an empty values clause.

Furthermore, I think you should remove all the `update class` statements as well. Those statements will update the classid field of all records in the class table unconditionally for all records.

Comment: thank you, it works. also thank you for pointing out my mistake on the `update class` statements